# What is the best and most pythonic method to design an interactive fiction library?

Tags: python, interactive

For anyone who does interactive fiction dev as well as python dev, I have a question: I am at an impasse for a design choice about an IF library made in python, complete with all the bells and whistles, development was going great until I came up with an idea that would fix a couple issues I've had to workaround and makes the code look a little more compliant with the *actual* interpreter I'm basing the library off of, but to me it seems, I don't know, a little controverisial. If you were coding in an IF python library, would you rather do something like this for each object:

```py
main = ObjMap()


@main.room
class my_room(Room):
    # ... other important stuff like the name and description
    west = "my_other_room"

@main.room
class my_other_room(Room):
    east = "my_room"
    def some_method(self, args, params):
        pass
```

OR something like this (I need the map so that there is an object that contains the entire game):

```py
main = ObjMap()

my_room = Room()  # ... important stuff goes in the constructor...
my_other_room = Room()
with my_other_room:
    def some_method(self, args, params):
        pass
main.create_connection(my_room, "west", my_other_room, "east")
```

Each do the same thing, and are close to the same size, but I'm not sure what other python coders think of each technique. These are the best options without just making a new prog. language dedicated to IF. *ahem TADS* If this is totally the wrong place to ask please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are going for a framework or a library.

- Framework: I would go with the first one. It looks more like a DSL, which is a good thing. You want to minimize the boilerplate and make it as easy and as clear as possible for the common cases. Python is a great choice for making DSLs based on the Python language, as long as speed is not a big concern and Turing-completeness is needed.
- Library: I would go with the second one. It looks like an API that allows you to build the graph of rooms and commands, but where the actual data comes from and how to pass it to the library is up to the user of the library. The user is likely to implement a DSL themselves, possibly reading from text files, etc.

So it depends on what you want to achieve!

Comment: I specifically did want to make this *without* a special language as there are already a lot of things like that, so there'd be no reason to make it or use it. I wanted to extend the creation of IF into a general programming language not restricted to a custom language syntax (so like one could make web calls or port their program to Tkinter, etc.) So I'm going for more of a "library". Thank you!